# How to add initial value without edit initial value on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I added initial value like this, But user can edit initial text. How to disable to edit initial value? ***But user can be able to add value with initial value?***

```
 var _myController = TextEditingController(text: "https://");
```

Output should be like this

```
print(url);
```

**https://(user_type_value)**

Comment: no no, user allow to write but without remove https://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You can try this logic, this way `https://` will always be shown to the user, if user enters a url without `https://` we are good, and if a user enters url with `https://` we are again good.

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    TextField(
      controller: _controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(prefixText: "https://"),
    ),
    RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Submit"),
      onPressed: () {
        String text = _controller.text.toString();
        if (!text.contains("https://")) {
          text = "https://" + text;
        }
        // text here will always have https://
      },
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: what happen user type `http://`? not `https://` I tried, Output is: ```https://http://sample.com```

Comment: Use regEx in prefixText for `http`, `https` or any other protocols for that matter you want, then you will be able to properly able to distinguish all protocols.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need something like masked edit, look here: https://github.com/benhurott/flutter-masked-text/blob/master/README.md